# QR code Reader Exception for Zxing

Tags: xamarin.ios, zxing

I am using the following code after taking a picture using the camera.

---

```
UIimage img = e.Info[UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;
imagePicker.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
try
{

    var srcbitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img);

     Reader barcodeReader = new MultiFormatReader();
     LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(srcbitmap,(int)image.Size.Width, (int)image.Size.Height);
  BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
  var result = barcodeReader.decode(bitmap);
```

---

I am getting an exception from the Zxing library. Have anyone faced such an issue ?
If so please do help.

I took the Zxing library from https://github.com/JohnACarruthers/zxing.MonoTouch

Comment: ... what exception? NotFoundException is normal, just means it wasn't detected.

Comment: The Exception is from the LuminsSource constructor and bitmap.cs(getPixel) funstions .

Comment: ... and, what Exception is it? You're not really giving much info.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Iam getting the following exception: Exception : System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
  at System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel (Int32 x, Int32 y) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working :)

It was happening because of the large image size. I reduced the image size as follows

```
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new SizeF(480,320));
            image.Draw(new RectangleF(0,0,200,200));
            UIImage smallImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
```

And it worked :)